# javascript image rotation within 2 seperate divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have previously achieved something similar to this using the code below but I have no idea how I did it and am unable to reverse engineer my code. I have two divs called `advert 1` and `advert 2` and I need them after 1 minute to rotate to another image. Each `div` will have 3 images. Below is the code I used before years ago, however I do not know how I used it.

Javascript:

```
var rotators = [
{ id: 'advert1', images: ['advert1.jpg', 'advert2.jpg', 'advert3.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 },
{ id: 'advert2', images: ['advert4.jpg', 'advert5.jpg', 'advert6.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 }
];

var updateImages = function() {
for (var i=0; i < rotators.length; i++) {
    var rotator = rotators[i];
    rotator.selectedIndex++;
    if (rotator.selectedIndex >= rotator.images.length) {
        rotator.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById(rotator.id).src = rotator.images[rotator.selectedIndex];
}
};
var timer = setInterval(updateImages, 300000);
```

Comment: what's the problem? To change it to 1 minute just change `300000` to `60000`

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how i used this code before, i just know i did lol

Comment: What is your question? Did you try to add the code to your website? Were there any error messages in the console?

Comment: check this example using your code it might enlighten you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c166kukz/)

Comment: its still not working when out in my website do i need to call any jquery?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] --c2 init--
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] timeout: 0 (number)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] prev: .prev (string)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] next: .next (string)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] slides: .c-item (string)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] carouselVisible: 5 (number)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] pauseOnHover: true (boolean)
jquery.cycle.js:580 [cycle2] fx: carousel (string)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load this library somewhere on your page: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/, but the file doesn't exits. The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you posted, though.